# Android Studio click on generated Navigation Direction to redirect into XML instead of generated files

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation

With the Navigation component, when using Navigation directions and using them as `MyFragmentDirections.actionGoToFragment2()`, in some projects when i do `cmd+click` on the `actionGoToFragment2()` it opens the XML where the actual action is.

But, in some other projects, it opens the `generated Kotlin files` and i have to navigate by hand to the direction's XML.

How do i auto enable to **navigate to XML when clicking on the directions**?

Thanks!